# Reset multiple Alarms after device reboot

Tags: android, android-intent, alarmmanager

I see this question has been asked many times before but I just want to make sure I have it right.

After my device is rebooted my `BroadcastReceiver` (**AlarmReceiverBoot extends BroadcastReceiver**) is fired and I am able to Toast in

```
if ("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED".equals(intent.getAction())) { TOAST }
```

Do I have to keep track of every alarm set by a user, including all set extras, and reset the multiple alarms from them?  All of the alarms are single shots - no repeats.

If so, how would I do this?  I'm guessing loop thru an array.

Any help would be great.  Thank you.

Comment: I believe the answer is Yes. Since posting I read that services get dumped on device reboot and I must keep track of each set alarm and their extras.  The easiest way I can think of doing this is a SQLite table, getters-setters class for reminders, every an alarm set - add to table, and every time an alarm is fired remove that ID from table.  On reboot, loop thru DB list and set new alarms in BroadcastReceiver.